# What is this header error caused by?

Tags: c++

I'm using the header file "sales.item"

I'm writing a little program and it is telling me that the header file, not my program, has an error. Somehow that last line isn't right. The error is saying that the string isbn is private.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"

int main()
{
Sales_item item1, item2;
std::cin >> item1 >> item2;
if (item1.isbn() == item2.isbn()) { // this checks if item1 and item2 are same book
```

Comment: What are the contents of Sales_item class? Most likely the method isbn() is private inside Sales_item class. Make it public

Comment: If you think the problem is in `Sales_item.h`, then why have you shown us some other file?

Comment: @init6 I did. Now the issue is with the "if" line I posted. Saying "no match to call to std::string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that your class is defined something like this:

```
class Sales_item
{
    std::string isbn;
}
```

Classes and structs have public, private, and protected labels for their member data, and classes have their members labelled as private by default.  You should change it to read:

```
class Sales_item
{
    public:
        std::string isbn;
}
```

EDIT:

When you add `()` (with or without parameters) to an identifier, you are telling the compiler to call it like a function.  Take out the ()'s and your code should work.

Comment: "private:
    std::string isbn;" is how it looks in the header file

Comment: @Raigeki: That's a non-difference.

Comment: @Raigeki Your code shows calling a function called `isbn()`, so I was guessing that you had a function which returned a private `isbn` variable.  If adding the public label to what you are calling is not fixing your issue, please post your header file.

Comment: @Namfuak After making it public, the error stopped in the header and is now on the "if" line I posted in OP. It is saying "no match to call to std::string"

Comment: @Namfuak Thanks I got it to work by removing the call operator. Question, what situation would call for it[call operator] vs the dot operator, especially in the context I'm using. The book I am following uses both operators.

Comment: The dot only calls a member function or accesses a member variable, the parenthesis don't have to do with that.  For example, `std::string` has a member function `size()`, so I can call that on `isbn` (a string variable) by using `isbn.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Sales_item` class you forgot to make the `isbn` method `public`, and left it at its default `private` visibility.

It should, in short, read something like this:

```
class Sales_item
{
  public:
    return_value isbn();
}
```

Without the `public:` line it will be `private` by default in C++ classes.

Comment: I made it public but now the error is with the line "if" in my code in OP. It says "no match to call to std::string"